# Trying to scrape data from site that does not have a unique table reference or unique url

Tags: python, web-scraping, statistics

I am unable to find a unique way of pulling each yearly / stage tables data when looking through sites HTML, I believe this is to do with the way the site works as all date for stages and years are filter, other sites I have worked before have not been configured this way, looking forward to seeing how this is done.

This is what I was trying and having no luck with before trying to map the dataframe

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Downloading contents of the web page
url = "https://www.letour.fr/en/history"
data = requests.get(url).text

# Creating BS4 object
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

#  locating table from TDF HTML
table = soup.find_all('table', class_='rankingTable')
```

The end goal is to pull all table data by year / stage and specifying that year and stage in the output, followed by the riders stage results.

| Year | Stage | Rank | Rider | Rider No.| Team | Times | Gap | B | P |

Comment: It's dynamic (loaded with js) and the ajax APIs look rather difficult to replicate with requests. You should try with selenium